# Display two unrelated select queries with no mutual fields in one firebird procedure

Tags: sql, select, firebird, firebird-3.0

How to properly display two unrelated select queries with no mutual fields in on procedure?

```
Table1
        Number
          1
          2
          3
          4
          5

Table2
        Letter
          a
```

When i try to call them using this procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE
RETURNS(
  Number SMALLINT,
  Letter Varchar)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT
      A.Number,
      B.Letter
    FROM Table1 A, Table2 B
    INTO
      :Number,
      :Letter
  DO
    BEGIN
      SUSPEND;
    END
END;
```

i get this result

```
Number Letter
  1      a
  2      a
  3      a
  4      a
  5      a
```

here is my desired result

```
   Number Letter
      1      a
      2      
      3      
      4      
      5
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to do something like this?

Comment: i have to show two select procedure in one xtratable in a report. I am using devexpress and i think this is the best thing to do. To combine the two select queries in one procedure

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a result set of unrelated sets 'zipped' up, you should assign each row from either table with a row number (using Firebird 3's [`row_number()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-windowfuncs-row-number)) and then join on that (using an outer join, so it doesn't matter which has more rows).

This would result in a query that looks like:

```
select a.number, b.letter
from (select row_number() over() as t1nr, number from table1) a
full outer join (select row_number() over() as t2nr, letter from table2) b
    on a.t1nr = b.t2nr
```

Note, depending on your needs, you may want to specify an explicit order for `row_number()`, for example `row_number() over(order by number)` and `row_number() over(order by letter)`.

Alternatively, you could use the `CURSOR` support in Firebird's stored procedures and manual control the iteration, this gets quite messy and hard to follow though.

You could do something like I show below (I'm using Firebird 3, but replacing those booleans with a smallint and using 1 and 0 should work with Firebird 2.0 - 2.5). For readability I used table names `numbers` and `letters` instead of `table1` and `table2`

```
execute block returns (number integer, letter char(1))
as
  declare cur_numbers cursor for (select number from numbers);
  declare cur_letters cursor for (select letter from letters);
  declare all_numbers_fetched boolean = false;
  declare all_letters_fetched boolean = false;
begin
  open cur_numbers;
  open cur_letters;
  while (true) do
  begin
    
    if (not all_numbers_fetched) then
    begin
      -- fetch a single row from numbers
      fetch cur_numbers into :number;
      if (row_count = 0) then
      begin
        -- all numbers fetched
        close cur_numbers;
        all_numbers_fetched = true;
        number = null;
      end
    end
    
    if (not all_letters_fetched) then
    begin
      -- fetch a single row from letters
      fetch cur_letters into :letter;
      if (row_count = 0) then
      begin
        -- all letters fetched
        close cur_letters;
        all_letters_fetched = true;
        letter = null;
      end
    end
    
    if (all_numbers_fetched and all_letters_fetched) then
      leave;

    suspend;
  end
end
```